# Vue router working erraticaly

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I've spent the whole day trying to figure out what is making this example fail:

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter);

var PlayerDetail =  {
  template: '<div>FOO</div>'
};
var PlayerList =  {
  template: '<div>BAR</div>'
};

var routes = [{
  path: '/player',
  component: PlayerList
}, { 
  path: '/detail',
  component: PlayerDetail
}];

var appRouter = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

var appVm = new Vue({
  appRouter
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <router-link to="/player">foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/detail">bar</router-link>
  </p>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

If it's exactly like this one that works:

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter);

var Foo = {
  template: '<div>FOO</div>'
};
var Bar = {
  template: '<div>BAR</div>'
};

var routes = [{
  path: '/foo',
  component: Foo
}, {
  path: '/bar',
  component: Bar
}];

var router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

var appVm = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <router-link to="/foo">foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">bar</router-link>
  </p>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

As you can see, both examples are practically the same code, but in the first one, I'm getting TypeError: route is undefined when the router is rendering.

Does anyone else see something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `Vue` constructor `{ appRouter }`, which is shorthand for `{ appRouter: appRouter }`. The `Vue` constructor is expecting an object with a `router` property, not an `appRouter` property.

You need to name your router object `router` exactly if you are going to pass it in using the object property shorthand:

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter);

var PlayerDetail =  {
  template: '<div>FOO</div>'
};
var PlayerList =  {
  template: '<div>BAR</div>'
};

var routes = [{
  path: '/player',
  component: PlayerList
}, { 
  path: '/detail',
  component: PlayerDetail
}];

var router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

var appVm = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <router-link to="/player">foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/detail">bar</router-link>
  </p>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I think path and component combination is not correct

```js
var routes = [{
  path: '/player',
  component: PlayerDetail
}, { 
  path: '/detail',
  component: PlayerList
}];
```